How to see individual users that access a specific page
I'm currently using GA and Tag Manager on my website.
I need a report that contains the individual users that access a specific page in a specific timeframe. I do not care whether they did access one time or multiple times.
Semthing like this:
Page domanin.com/xxx

User 1
User 2
...

I am using both GA and Tag Manager, with custom properties pushed to the system (like for example my User's IDs), but I can't figure out how to generate the report I need.
Can anybody help?
THank you very much.

Have a look at this u can use a api to fetch data
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/rest/v1beta/properties/runReport
